# One ip, many domains - redirecting to correct container

Tags: docker, dns

I have server with one ip and five domains redirect to this ip. I want to have on this server five different container and want to access to them by domain. What is the easiest solution for this?
I try this:

```
docker run -it -p 80:8080 --label com.docker.ucp.mesh.http=external_route=my1.example.com,internal_port=80 container_1
```

This solution also redirect my2.example.com, my3.example.com, my4.example.com, my5.example.com to this container and then I try to

```
docker run -it -p 80:8080 --label com.docker.ucp.mesh.http=external_route=my2.example.com,internal_port=80 container_2
```

I see error that port 80 is already used.

All docker are http servers, what is the easiest way to redirect by domain to correct container?

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is to make them listen on different private IP's and use Nginx as a reverse proxy to handle the requests on the docker host.

you can configure Nginx like this per site:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```